# Configure software settings from ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, settings

Is it possible to configure the software settings from the Ubuntu terminal?
Suppose I have notepad++ installed. I need to change the language from the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Notepad++ is no native linux application. The notepad++ snap runs under wine, making this a bad example. Generally, the answer to your question will depend on the specific application.

Comment: Erhm yes, you can configure everything in Ubuntu from the terminal. But it seems you want to configure a specific setting of a running Wine application, which can be more tricky. Why do you need this?

Comment: Actually, I need this for different applications but notepad++ as demo.

Comment: As stated, it's a bad example. Please use the exact example, as this will depend on the application and what you want to do.